# What iOS 7 apps from Apple use UIWebView with native navigation, if any?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app

I've just finished reading an article about building hybrid apps that use native navigation to control web views [1].

From what I understand, Apple's own App Store app used an approach like this in the past. I'm trying to find out if they've dropped this approach today (May 2014) in iOS 7. Are there any of Apple's own apps that still take this approach?

If Apple still produces their own UIWebView dependent apps, what are the classes they'll be using to achieve this?

Many thanks,
A web dev researching iOS + hybrid app development

[1] http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3743-hybrid-sweet-spot-native-navigation-web-content

Comment: I'd be interested to know about any iOS7 or Android apps that are using this approach, not just Apple's own apps.